# Get the user name and comment with article id in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I have 3 tables users, comments, and articles. I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('/article/{id}', 'ArticlesController@view');
```

What I want is when I accessing that route I will get User Name and their comment in this article id.

so here's my view function in ArticlesController:

```
public function view($id){
        $article = Article::with('comments')->find($id);
        return view('front.single',compact('article'));
}
```

and here's my single.blade.php code:

```
<div class="single-grid">
      @section('content')
         <h1>{{ $article->title }}</h1>
         <p>{{ $article->content }}</p>
      @show
</div>          

<div class="comment-list">
@foreach($article->comments as $comment)
    <ul class="comment-list">
    <div class="comment-grid">
        <img src="/images/avatar.png" alt=""/>
        <div class="comment-info">
            <h4>{{ $comment->user->name }}</h4>
            <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
            <h5>{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</h5>
            <a href="#">Reply</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</ul>
@endforeach
</div>
```

I'm not sure what how to do it since it gives me error like this:

```
"Call to undefined relationship [comment] on model [App\User]."
```

I already define the relation in each model. here's my articles model:

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

My comment model:

```
 public function article(){
    $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
}
public function user(){
    $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and here's my User model:

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
}
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
public function publish(Article $article){
    $this->articles()->save($article);
}
```

here's my table structure:
-**users**(id,name,email,password,remember_token,created_at,updated_at)
-**comments**(id,user_id,article_id,comment,created_at,updated_at)
-**articles**(id,user_id,title,content,created_at,updated_at)

so how can I can User Name just by using this route? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on Your Comment Model, You need to replace articles to article

```
public function article(){
        $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
    }
```

also, if you want to get user specific comments, than you need to change your controller action code from

```
$article = Article::with('user.comment')->find($id) to
$article = Article::with('user.comments')->find($id);
```

Comment: now i get this errors "Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\front\commentList.blade.php) (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\front\ ▶"

Comment: if you want to list out all the comments of article, than you only need to attach comments with your article.

$article = Article::with('comments')->find($id);

Comment: on your comment model, you need to change users to user

public function user(){
        $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

Comment: when i do all that i got this errors App\Comment::user must return a relationship instance.

Comment: can you please update your question with all changes which I mentioned above, so I can get better idea

Comment: Can you please share database table structure of comments, articles and users table in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156970/discussion-between-henra-and-ankit-patel).

Comment: Did you check chat window?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue comes from the use of **compact** function : an array is passed to the view instead of an object.
Can you try it like this :

```
// Controller
public function view($id) {
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    return view('front.single', $article);
}

<!-- View -->
@foreach($article->comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment->user->name }}
    {{ $comment->comment }}
    {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: it give me this kind of erros "Undefined variable: article (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\front\single.blade.php)"